# Set values to an object of type NSObject after adding it to an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

I created a class named as Tutoral which is a sub class of `NSObject`, and it has following synthesized properties Title and Url.Then in my viewcontroller I created an instance of the Tutorial class.I also Created an `NSMutableArray` object and initialised. I added my tutorial object instance to the array. Then I set the properties such as Title = "mytitle" and Url = "myurl". In another place I fetched the tutorial object instance from the array and `NSLog` its Title and Url property values.It shows "mytitle" and "myurl" respectively.
My confusion is that why tutorial object instance which is inside the arry shows its property values. The tutorial object properties are set after that object is added to the array. Follwing are my tested code.

```
NSMutableArray *newTutorials = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

Tutorial *tutorial = [[Tutorial alloc] init];

[newTutorials addObject:tutorial];

tutorial.title = @"mytitle";

tutorial.url = @"myurl";

Tutorial *objNew = [newTutorials objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"Title %@",objNew.title);

NSLog(@"Url %@",objNew.url);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is exactly ? newObj is equal to tutorial, since you assign it to tutorial stored into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the following line of code executed,

```
[newTutorials addObject:tutorial];
```

What it does is , **it add the address (reference) of tutorial object which you created in the previous line to the array newTutorials**.

Your confusion is this : " You haven't set the values for the tutorial object **inside the array** but why is it displaying **mytitle** and **myurl** when you `NSLog`ed the propeties of tutorials?" The answer is simple "**You've not stored the tutorial** object inside the array but **you have stored a reference to the tutorial object**"

Since when you've stored the reference and you've done the following to tutorial object :

```
tutorial.title = @"mytitle";

tutorial.url = @"myurl";
```

When you try to print the properties of the reference stored in the array, it prints **mytitle** and **myurl** because that is what you've assigned to the actual object's properties.

Comment: Thank you very much.You said that I havn't stored the tutorial object inside array.Is there any way to store the tutorail object in the array?.

Answer (score 2):

When you add an object to an array, the array just keeps a reference to that object (a pointer). It doesn't create a copy of that object.

So, in the code example above, you're always dealing with the same instance of `Tutorial`:

- First, you create a new `Tutorial` with `alloc` and `init`, and store a reference to it with the `tutorial` pointer.
- Then you add it to your array. Your array *retains* the object, which means it keeps a reference to it.
- Then you set the `title` and `url` properties of your existing object.
- Then you grab *another* reference to the **same** object, and call it `objNew`. You get this reference by asking the array for a pointer to its first object.
- You then print the properties of the object.